# How to express (string,string[ ],string[ ]) at C#

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner and being wondering what I'm doing wrong here? I've tried several different ways to make this "new Exercise" but always end up getting error codes. How to properly add some values to it as there are two string[] within?

```
    public string name;
    public string[] times=new string[2];
    public string[] places=new string[2];


     public Exercise(string name,string[] times, string[] places)
    {
    this.name= name;
    this.times[2] = times[2];
    this.places[2] = places[2];
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)

    {


    //System.Collections.ArrayList exercise = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

        Exercise[] J1=new Exercise[5];

        J1[5]  = new Exercise("junior","Wedn 9:30","Frid 9:30","Gym","");

    //exercise.Add(J1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor gets 3 arguments that two of them are arrays of string.
In Your code you pass 5 string arguments. Instead you should this:

```
J1[0] = new Exercise("junior",
            new[] {"Wedn 9:30", "Frid 9:30"},
            new[]
            {
                "Gym", ""
            }
        );
```

**Also you are trying to create an Exercise in 5th member of array. Arrays start at zero! so an Exercise with the length of 5 has 5 members: J1[0],J1[1],J1[2],J1[3],J1[4]**

Comment: Happy to help my friend!
if I answered your question I'll appreciate it if you accept it as the right answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Good point I used accidentally the fifth member for no reason. I already tried adding data the way you suggested. For some reason, it gives an error CS1526: Unexpected symbol `{' . Any idea why? (sorry for deleted reply, didn't know enter sends the message)

Comment: sorry my friend I had a typo Edited the answer

Comment: Thank you very much! It accepted it. Now I have error elsewhere but that's a whole another story.

Comment: happy to help ;) hope U fix 'em soon

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in `J1[5]  = new Exercise("junior","Wedn 9:30","Frid 9:30","Gym","");`

1. J1 is of length 5, that means from index 0 to 4 and you are assigning at 5 location.
2. You are passing 5 args to contractor whereas constructor accepts only 3 (two of them are an array of string).

   `String times[] = {"Wedn 9:30","Frid 9:30"};
   String places[]= {"Gym",""}; 
   J1[0]  = new Exercise("junior", times, places);`

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, it gives an error CS1526: Unexpected symbol `{' . Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks. This did it: J1[0] = new Exercise("junior",
            new[] {"Wedn 9:30", "Frid 9:30"},
            new[]
            {
                "Gym", ""
            }
        );

Comment: @KP2 glad to help!